# Why andmap returns #t in this case?

Tags: lisp, racket

I am using Racket and Dr. Racket.

There is built-in function called [andmap](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=andma#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29).

The built-in version of andmap works this way:

```
> (andmap positive? '(1 2 3))

#t
```

Function number usually works as:

```
(number? 3)
> #t

(number? '())
>#f
```

I do not get why this happens:

```
(andmap number? '())

> #t
```

I think the result should be false.

The documentation says:

```
*If the lsts are empty, then #t is returned.*
```

Why on earth would that make sense? I do not see it. I am curious about the design choices of languages, specially new ones, like Racket.

Comment: Note that this works the exact same way in logics, that is `forall x in X: p(x)` is true, regardless of what `p` is, when `X` is empty. This is known as [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth.

Comment: Also, for what it’s worth, Racket is hardly “new”—it is almost as old as Haskell and Python, and it’s a little *older* than both Java and Ruby. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason `(andmap pred '())` returns `#t` is exactly the same reason `(and)` returns `#t`… but that’s perhaps not the most useful explanation, is it? The real answer is that `#t` is the **identity** for logical AND, just like 0 is the additive identity and 1 is the multiplicative identity:

```
> (+)
0
> (*)
1
> (and)
#t
> (or)
#f
```

The idea here is that the identity will not change the output when combined with any given input. For example, just like `(+ 0 x)` is always `x` and `(* 1 x)` is always `x`, `(and #t x)` is always `x` and `(or #f x)` is always `x`. This is a useful property to have, since it cooperates well with the idiomatic way to sum a list in Scheme, `(apply + lst)`:

```
> (apply + '(1 2 3))
6
> (apply + '())
0
```

Similarly, `(apply * lst)` can be used instead of a separate `product` function. The `and` and `or` operators cannot be used with `apply`, since they are short-circuiting and are thus implemented as macros instead of functions, but `andmap` and `ormap` implement that functionality instead.

---

If that argument doesn’t seem satisfying enough to you, you can also think about these things in their plain English definitions to come to the same conclusion. What does the `andmap` operation *mean*? Well, it asks a question: “Do all of the elements in this list satisfy a predicate?” On an empty list, the answer will always be **yes**, given that you cannot possibly produce a counterexample to that claim.

In contrast, `ormap` is the dual: “Does at least one of the elements in this list satisfy a predicate?” The answer will always be **no**, since it’s impossible to produce any element at all, so producing one that satisfies a predicate is surely impossible.